# bind data to repeater from multiple tables from a single dataset using #eval()

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, repeater

i have a stored procedure returning multiple select. the result from this procedure is stored in a dataset. So the dataset contain 2 table, table1 & table2.

*table1*
[View Table1 Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt2x3.png)

table2 [View Table2 Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RYSP.png)

i have a repeater control like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrDetails" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table style="width: 100%" class="table-popup" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Payment Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Payer Type
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Payer Description
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Payment Method
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Check No
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Amount
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        &nbsp;
                    </th>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("PaymentDate")%>  //from table1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("PayerType")%>  //from table1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("PayerDescription")%> //from table1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("PaymentMethod")%> //from table1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("CheckNo")%> //from table1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Amount")%> //from table1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="Images/expand.png" alt="click here to see details" onclick='ToggleDisplay(<%#Container.ItemIndex %>);'
                        style="cursor: pointer; height: 15px; width: 15px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='coldiv<%#Container.ItemIndex %>' style="display: none;">
                <td colspan="7">
                    <div>
                        <table style="width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    s
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("lName") %> //from table2
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    s
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("fName") %> //from table2
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    s
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("mName") %> //from table2
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    sd
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("city") %> //from table2
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

how to bind the data from table2 to this repeater. i'm getting error says the field names from table2 not found. please help.

is there any way like Eval("Table[0].PaymentDate") or Eval("Table[0].city")

Comment: Please show query that you are using to fill dataset

Comment: i just want to know how to bind data from two datatable from a dataset. like Eval("Table[0].PaymentDate") or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new temporary `DataTable` and put your required columns from your `Dataset` into the temporary `DataTable` and bind it in the simple way like you are doing.